# How can i generate consecutive codes with redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

i would like to generate a consecutive codes, like PR00001, EC00002, TG00003 and so on, the first two letters have to be from the name and the last name.

my pseudocode is

```
recovery the number from database 00001, add +1 then i will get 00002 and concat with the letters
PR+00002
```

In order to use `redis` to generate that code, to me is simple why should i use redis to generate that code?

how should i implement that code using redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the correct idea. Use INCR to increment the counter. One of the benefits of Redis is that it is single threaded and you can atomically update the value, even with many threads or processes making concurrent requests.

I was able to repro your issue. It is possible that your cache is not configured to use Redis, or there is an issue with the `Rails.cache.increment` command.

```
irb(main):003> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore options={:compress=>true, :compress_threshold=>1024}>
irb(main):004> Rails.cache.write 'foo', 1
=> true
irb(main):005> Rails.cache.read 'foo'
=> nil
```

You can use Redis without the cache:

```
r = Redis.new
r.set :foo, 1
=> "OK"
r.incr :foo
=> 2
r.get :foo
=> "2"
```

Reference: https://redis.io/commands/incr/

Comment: how can i add zeros like this 00002 ?

Comment: `.to_s.rjust(5, "0")`